How to show a grid on the page when an element is being dragged/resized?
I have a page where you can drag/resize boxes to design your own dashboard layout. It has a 12 column format.
I want to show the grid lines temporarily when an item is being dragged/resized, so that user has an idea of placement options and columns.
How can I show those lines on the page via css?

you can use canvas and javascript combination(used by sites like desmos,figma..) which would suit if your boxes are rendered in canvas,if not the best method would be to use a grid line image as background of body or div(you may generate 12x12 grid in any online site,or do it dynamically using js) however a code of what you had done previously would help to give best answer(there are few other ways to make those grid lines).

To move a block between columns you can use Drag Events. In these events, you add or remove CSS styles. As for changing the size of the block, you can use the mousemove and mouseup events.
Also, if you're working with React, you can use react-resizable.
You can check all drag events here: Drag Events Link
